# 1980s book with a teenage boy and girl who both have some kind of power. In one scene, the boy teleports a toy train from a store window into his hand

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, telekinesis

Looking for an early 1980s young adult book. The only things I can remember from the book are no help at all searching.

There's a teenage boy and girl who both have some kind of power. In one scene, the boy accidentally teleports a toy train from a store window into his hand, and the girl makes the clouds move to reveal the moon.

I also seem to recall some scene where they're holding some kind of metal device (a "tintinabulum?" Something with a Latin name?) that's cone-shaped, to open a door into another dimension/place.
I also seem to recall one of the words being "elepanth" (not a typo) but that doesn't get me anywhere either.

It's NOT *The Girl With Silver Eyes* (1980) by Willo Davis Roberts, nor *Into the Dream* (1979) by William Sleator.